# hey can anyone help me with this sign up website project I'm trying to build

Tags: javascript, html

thanks in advance!
following is the full html with in-page script.
it's supposed to function both as register user, sign in user, and remove user from the system.
when I try to press any buttons it says the functions don't exist for some reason - and it doesn't change the intended

to show a message.

there is a global array for the user object 3 inputs for the registration (username, password, verify), two for both login & remove user, each has a button that onclicks its own unique function, given the details are right it should make actions on the global array.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
       
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="website_1.css">
        <title>nave's website</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <form name="first">
            <h2>Register</h2>
            <input type="text" name="regUser" placeholder="enter user"> <br>
            <input type="text" name="regPass" placeholder="enter password"><br>
            <input type="text" name="regVer" placeholder="verify password"><br>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="reg()">Register</button><br>
        </form>
        <p id="text"></p><br>
        <form name="log">
            <h2>Log in</h2>
            <input type="text" name="logUser" placeholder="enter user"><br>
            <input type="text" name="logPass" placeholder="enter password"><br>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="log()">login</button><br>
            <p id="log"></p><br>
        </form>
    
        <h2>Remove</h2>
        <form name="rem">
            <input type="text" name="remUser" placeholder="enter user"><br>
            <input type="text" name="remPass" placeholder="enter password"><br>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="rem()">Remove</button><br>
            <p id="rem"></p><br>
        </form>
    
        <p id="man"></p>
    </body>
    <script>
    var users = [{}];
    function userExist(x) {
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            if (users[i].username == x) {
                return arr[i]
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    function reg() {
        var x = document.forms[first][regUser].value;
        var y = document.forms[first][regPass].value;
        var z = document.forms[first][regVer].value;
        if (y != z) {
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "passwords dont match";
        } else if (x == "" || y == "") {
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "password & username are mandatory";
        } else if (userExist(x) != false) {
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "user already exists! try logging in";
        } else {
            user = {
                username: x,
                password: y
            }
            users.push(user);
        }
    }
    
    function log() {
        var x = document.forms[log][logUser].value;
        var y = document.forms[log][logPass].value;
        var q = userExist(x);
    
        if (q != false) {
            if (q.password == y) {
                document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "Login!";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "password incorrect!";
            }
        } else {
            document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "username doesn't exist!";
    
        }
    }
    
    function rem() {
        var x = document.forms[rem][remUser].value;
        var y = document.forms[rem][remPass].value;
        var q = users.indexOf(userExist(x));
    
        if (q == -1) {
            document.getElementById("rem").innerHTML = "username doesn't exist!";
        } else {
            if (users[q].password == y) {
                users.splice(q, 1)
                document.getElementById("rem").innerHTML = "user removed successfully!";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("rem").innerHTML = "password incorrect!";
    
            }
    
        }
    
    
    }
    
    document.getElementById("man").innerHTML = "say hi";
    </script>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `name="log"` and `name="rem"` will result in the function `rem` and `log` to be *overwritten*, so at the time `onclick="log()"` or `onclick="rem()"` is evaluated, those variables point to the `form` elements and not to the functions anymore.

That's one reason why you should not use those `on...` attributes to register event listeners, you should use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

As a quick fix you can either rename your functions or your html elements, so that there is no conflict between the names.

Besides that `document.forms[first][regUser]` would also not work, it would not access the `form` with the name `first` and then it's input with the name `regUser`. It would try to access the form with the name that is stored in the variable `first` and then the input with the name that is stored in the variable `regUser`.

What you are looking for is to write either `document.forms['first']['regUser']` or `document.forms.first.regUser`

To avoid naming conflicts and pollution of the global namespace you should wrap your code into a [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) `(function() { /*your code*/ })()`

```js
(function() {
  'use strict'
  var users = [{}];

  function userExist(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      if (users[i].username == x) {
        return arr[i]
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

  }

  function reg() {
    var x = document.forms.first.regUser.value;
    var y = document.forms.first.regPass.value;
    var z = document.forms.first.regVer.value;
    if (y != z) {
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "passwords dont match";
    } else if (x == "" || y == "") {
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "password & username are mandatory";
    } else if (userExist(x) != false) {
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "user already exists! try logging in";
    } else {
      user = {
        username: x,
        password: y
      }
      users.push(user);
    }
  }

  function log() {
    var x = document.forms.log.logUser.value;
    var y = document.forms.log.logPass.value;
    var q = userExist(x);

    if (q != false) {
      if (q.password == y) {
        document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "Login!";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "password incorrect!";
      }
    } else {
      document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "username doesn't exist!";

    }
  }

  function rem() {
    var x = document.forms.rem.remUser.value;
    var y = document.forms.rem.remPass.value;
    var q = users.indexOf(userExist(x));

    if (q == -1) {
      document.getElementById("rem").innerHTML = "username doesn't exist!";
    } else {
      if (users[q].password == y) {
        users.splice(q, 1)
        document.getElementById("rem").innerHTML = "user removed successfully!";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("rem").innerHTML = "password incorrect!";

      }

    }


  }

  document.getElementById('logBtn').addEventListener('click', log, false);
  document.getElementById('remBtn').addEventListener('click', rem, false);

  document.getElementById('regBtn').addEventListener('click', reg, false);

  document.getElementById("man").innerHTML = "say hi";
})()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="website_1.css">
  <title>nave's website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome!</h1>
  <form name="first">
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <input type="text" name="regUser" placeholder="enter user"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="regPass" placeholder="enter password"><br>
    <input type="text" name="regVer" placeholder="verify password"><br>
    <button id="regBtn" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Register</button><br>
  </form>
  <p id="text"></p><br>
  <form name="log">
    <h2>Log in</h2>
    <input type="text" name="logUser" placeholder="enter user"><br>
    <input type="text" name="logPass" placeholder="enter password"><br>
    <button id="logBtn" class="btn btn-default" type="button">login</button><br>
    <p id="log"></p><br>
  </form>

  <h2>Remove</h2>
  <form name="rem">
    <input type="text" name="remUser" placeholder="enter user"><br>
    <input type="text" name="remPass" placeholder="enter password"><br>
    <button id="remBtn" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Remove</button><br>
    <p id="rem"></p><br>
  </form>

  <p id="man"></p>
</body>
<script>
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You added variables like `rememberPass` and all but your never defined them that is why you are getting those errors.
I edited the snippet and all working fine.
Hope it helps..!!!

Happy Coding.. :D

```js
var users = [{}];
    function userExist(x) {
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            if (users[i].username == x) {
                return arr[i]
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    function reg() {
        var x = document.getElementsByName('regUser')[0].value;
        var y = document.getElementsByName('regPass')[0].value;
        var z = document.getElementsByName('regVer')[0].value
        if (y != z) {
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "passwords dont match";
        } else if (x == "" || y == "") {
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "password & username are mandatory";
        } else if (userExist(x) != false) {
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "user already exists! try logging in";
        } else {
            user = {
                username: x,
                password: y
            }
            users.push(user);
        }
    }
    
    function loginUser() {
        var x = document.getElementsByName('logUser')[0].value;
        var y = document.getElementsByName('logPass')[0].value;
        var q = userExist(x);
    
        if (q != false) {
            if (q.password == y) {
                document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "Login!";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "password incorrect!";
            }
        } else {
            document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "username doesn't exist!";
    
        }
    }
    
    function rememberPass() {
        var x = document.getElementsByName('remUser')[0].value;
        var y = document.getElementsByName('remPass')[0].value;
        var q = users.indexOf(userExist(x));
    
        if (q == -1) {
            document.getElementById("rem").innerHTML = "username doesn't exist!";
        } else {
            if (users[q].password == y) {
                users.splice(q, 1)
                document.getElementById("rem").innerHTML = "user removed successfully!";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("rem").innerHTML = "password incorrect!";
    
            }
    
        }
    
    
    }
    
    document.getElementById("man").innerHTML = "say hi";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
       
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="website_1.css">
        <title>nave's website</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <form name="first">
            <h2>Register</h2>
            <input type="text" name="regUser" placeholder="enter user"> <br>
            <input type="text" name="regPass" placeholder="enter password"><br>
            <input type="text" name="regVer" placeholder="verify password"><br>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="reg()">Register</button><br>
        </form>
        <p id="text"></p><br>
        <form name="log">
            <h2>Log in</h2>
            <input type="text" name="logUser" placeholder="enter user"><br>
            <input type="text" name="logPass" placeholder="enter password"><br>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="loginUser()">login</button><br>
            <p id="log"></p><br>
        </form>
    
        <h2>Remove</h2>
        <form name="rem">
            <input type="text" name="remUser" placeholder="enter user"><br>
            <input type="text" name="remPass" placeholder="enter password"><br>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="rememberPass()">Remove</button><br>
            <p id="rem"></p><br>
        </form>
    
        <p id="man"></p>
    </body>

    
    </html>
```

Comment: The reason for the error is that there is a naming conflict between the form elements and the functions which results, in `rem` and `log` pointing to the the forms instead of the functions at the time that `onclick` is evaluated, and that the OP forgot the quotation marks for the named access to the form elements.